# My z-index property is not getting set

Tags: css, z-index

I have a site with a log-in and a contact module, which is sliding out from the top-left side of the page. I have only one problem: the log-in module is working fine, but the contact module is going underneath the text, rather than above it. I set `z-index: 999999;` but, it still isn't working. I'm using `position: fixed;`

Comment: in the right side of the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving #iUngicontactForm from the table to the body tag will fix it.
The problem is that the z-index of an element is inherited from it's parent and it only applies to sibling elements. And as you're using fixed positioning, it's a quick fix.

So instead of something like this:

```
<body>
   <table>
     <tr><td>some content..</td></tr>
     <tr><td><div id="iUngicontactForm"></div></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

do this:

```
<body>
   <div id="iUngicontactForm"></div>
   <table>
     <tr><td>some content..</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you go up the dom tree until .art-block and set z-index there it fixes the problem. Confirmed in firebug. Not to the whole .art-block class but you'll need to add a new class there, or id, or inline -- to that specific .art-block.

Comment: but yeah, not very pleasant to go through all those tables within tables to be perfectly honest...