# Z-index Won't Work

Tags: css, z-index

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Css z-index problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965576/css-z-index-problem)

I have an issue where one image is infront of another and z-index doesnt seem to change it. 
I am trying to make it so the logo is on top of the gray bars image.

http://jsfiddle.net/vzPUw/

Can anyone explain to me why this is not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`z-index` only works with `position : relative/absolute/fixed` so give `position:relative` to your **logo**.

### http://jsfiddle.net/vzPUw/1/

**Updated**

### http://jsfiddle.net/vzPUw/3/

In this, I changed in the markup because we never put `block` element inside an `inline` element. `<a>` is an `inline` element & `h1` is a `block` element.

Comment: You really need to stop using the ` character to emphasize text that isn't code. Not only is it wrong, but it also makes your posts a nightmare to read. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

`z-index:0;` isn't a good value to use. You should use 1 as a minimum. 1 is the window base. 0 is technically below the window.

You simply need to call the right element (the anchor not the image within it) since the anchor is the container. Then it's a matter of margins and position for placement.

[**jsFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/vzPUw/2/)

Comment: Where did you read that a `z-index` of 0 is below the window?

Comment: @Scott this is wrong. Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/edPNv/). As you can see you can click on `z-index: 1;` before the `z-index: auto;` (base)

Answer (score 0):

see here i have change here...
-remove img tag for bar image and put background of header tag.. :)
-here i think you no need for position property and z-index.. :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ankur Patel</title>
</head>
<body style="width: 100%">
<header style="background-image: url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14080718/Final/images/bars.gif');background-repeat: repeat-x;">

    <a>
        <img alt="" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14080718/Final/images/rocketdesign.png">
    </a>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```