# z-index not setting in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I am using bootstrap and I have a modal that pops up and it works just fine only the `.modal-dialog` has a z-index of 0 even though it DOES get set. The `.modal-backdrop.n` has a `z-index` of 1030 and that works just fine so the `.modal-dialog` is being put in/under the black back drop.

Anyone know what the heck is going on here and how to fix?

Greatly appreciated!

[image: z-index being stupid]

I am well aware of stuff like this [z-index parent/child relationship](http://headertofooter.com/post/82162436590/why-z-index-doesnt-work-even-though-you-set)

Simple Bootstrap Modal [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lhalverson/vqshmrn0/)

**EDIT**

I upgraded my bootstrap version from v3.0.0 --> v3.3.2 and now everything is working fine. Just goes to show stay up to date with the latest versions. Thanks for all help everyone!

Comment: Both CreativeCreator and davidkonrad solutions work just odd I have to fix a Bootstrap css class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `z-index` only works on `position`ed elements. So set `position: relative;`, `position: absolute;`, or `position: fixed;`.

---

- Please never use `!important` if possible!

[Answer Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108696/z-index-wont-work) from sandeep.

Comment: hmmm it works, just very odd I have to do something to a Bootstrap class,`.modal-dialog`, to fix it.

Comment: Glad it works! Didnt you added the z-index yourself?

Comment: `.modal-dialog` is by bootstrap itself positioned to absolute, so it is very weird. There must be some third-party CSS involved here, overriding the bootstrap CSS.

Comment: I upgraded my bootstrap to v3.3.2 and it fixed the problem, was using v3.0.0, but this was the one I was using before the upgrade.