# CSS Use of z-index

Tags: css, z-index

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Css z-index problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965576/css-z-index-problem)

Is there away that I can get the border to appear behind the button?  `z-index:;` does not seem to be working in this situation.  [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7htb/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="scheduleArea">
   <button class="button"></button>     
</div>
 <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Send Now</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit Message</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.scheduleArea{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:right;
    margin:-15px 0 0 0;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.scheduleArea .button{
    width:100px;
    height:28px;
    background:url('../images/schedule.png') no-repeat center center;
    border:none;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.nav{
    float:right;
    height:57px;
    width:168px;
    margin:10px -100px 0 0;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:3px solid #B5B5B5;
    z-index:-20;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? your question is not clear

Comment: @Lollero In my jsfiddle the button is appearing behind the border.  I would like it to be the other way around.  There is only one "button" `<button>`.  Its in the image I have to produce

Comment: It only works with `position:...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

z-index doesn't work without position:relative or position:absolute.

Solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/k7htb/1/

Edit:

```
.nav{
    float:right;
    height:57px;
    width:168px;
    margin:10px -100px 0 0;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:3px solid #B5B5B5;
    z-index:-20;
    position:relative; /* This line is added */
}​
```

Comment: I gave a +1. However, please *add* the relevant code/CSS here as well, noting the changes.

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` only works on *positioned* elements. Adding `position:relative` to `.scheduleArea` and `.nav` should do the trick.